# What's special about the 'url' field of a Maven repository in gradle?

Tags: gradle

If I try to replace the URL with a variable substitution in the fragment below, I get an error about trying to apply authentication to a file URL.
What's the syntax?

```
maven {
  url 'https://example.com/artifactory/gradle-release'
  credentials {
    username = "${artifactory_user}"
    password = "${artifactory_password}"
  }
}
```

In other words, changing to:

```
url '${property_with_url}'
```

fails.

Comment: Did you try  `url "${myUrl}"` ?

Comment: Yes. I didn't work.